# Google Apps Script typeError in Google Form to Google Contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror, google-forms, google-contacts-api

I've been following along 'Learn Google spreadsheets's video 'Google Forms to Google Contacts (Gmail Contacts)' on YouTube to create a similar functionality, but I keep getting '
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'First name' of undefined addContact @ ...*'.

The *ContactsApp.createContact* takes 3 strings, which I believe is what I'm feeding it. So my thinking is the cell reference is the problem, but I can't figure out how to test the result of info['First name'].

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
function addContact(info) {

  const c = ContactsApp.createContact(info['First name'],info['Last name'],info['Email']);
  const cg = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();

  c.addToGroup(cg[4]);

}
```

| Timestamp | Email | First name | Last name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/14/2021 20:51:11 | jane_doe@email.com | Jane | Doe |

The spreadsheet is populated by a Google Form.

Comment: You table seems to have the wrong data in it.  Email should have an email in it.  Somethings wrong with the column alignment and the data

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an onForSubmit trigger then this line:

`const c = ContactsApp.createContact(info['First name'],info['Last name'],info['Email']);`

should be

`const c = ContactsApp.createContact(info.namedValues['First name'][0], info.namedValues['Last name'][0], info.namedValues['Email'][0]);`

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Form Submit for a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

> Assuming that the rest of your code is correct it should probably look like this as it typical that we use e for the trigger event object substitution paramenter

```
function addContact(e) {
  const c = ContactsApp.createContact(e.namedValues['First name'][0],e.namedValues['Last name'][0],e.namedValues['Email'][0]);
  const cg = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();
  c.addToGroup(cg[4]);
}
```